# How can I disable hints in Windows 7 or XP

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-xp

I want to disable hint when get my mouse over an item for example tree view or in Visual Studio.

Like in these screenshots [here](http://rghost.net/1820983/image.png) and [here](http://rghost.net/1820985/image.png).

Answer (score 3):

Click Start – Run - `regedit` and press enter. This will open the Windows Registry Editor.

Now, navigate through to

> [HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Advanced]

Look for the DWORD `ShowInfoTip`, right-click and select Modify and change the value data as required

> 1 – Enable ToolTips (Default)
>
> 0 – Disable ToolTips

Restart your machine. This should disable all the tooltip's.

Edit : Updated one more way to disable tooltips:

`HKEY_USERS\.DEFAULT\Control Panel\Desktop` . On the right pane, double-click `UserPreferencemask` and change the value to `3E 00 00 00`. Take a backup before you change this value.

Comment: Thanks very much, but should I restart windows?

Comment: Yes. I guess...

Comment: :( still I see hints.

Comment: Windows tool tips (operating system) are not the same as VS hints (application).