# How disable windows hints?

Tags: windows-xp

For example it says the space on my D drive is running out. Its annoying since I knew about it even before the system did and I'm ok with it. Other hint is saying that it can't show all recently used shortcuts in start menu - I really don't care.

How to turn it all off?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I disable hints in Windows 7 or XP](http://superuser.com/questions/149651/how-can-i-disable-hints-in-windows-7-or-xp)

Comment: @Moab The question is different, but the answer applies, since it didn't actually answer the question. Not a duplicate though.

Comment: That is why it says "possible duplicate"

Comment: @Moab It says "possible duplicate" because you didn't edit the comment after it was automatically created when you clicked next to "*This question covers exactly the same ground as earlier questions on this topic*". Mine was both fyi and for others who might do the same after only skimming over the other question, which is a lot less useful without the accompanying screenshots.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just like the "duplicate" answer said

```
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Advanced]
"ShowInfoTip"=dword:00000000
```

Answer (score 0):

Just save this to a .REG file, and import it.

```
REGEDIT4

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\Explorer]
"NoLowDiskSpaceChecks"=dword:00000001
```

Answer (score 0):

According to Microsoft's [Description of the Low Disk Space Notification in Windows XP](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/285107) you can turn it off by manually editing the registry.

Alternatively you can put the following 4 lines of text in a .reg file, right-click on it, and select "Merge".

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\Explorer]
"NoLowDiskSpaceChecks"=dword:00000001
```

It looks to me like @TheNewbie has one value too many...which probably doesn't hurt anything.